# Iterations in python consume whole memory - faulty code?

Tags: python, memory, sage

I have written some very simple trial-and-error code in Sage (a computer algebra system written in python where you can use regular python syntax in scripting). The little code snippet creates a polynomial and does some calculations with the coefficients, especially it determines the Groebner basis for the ideal generated by three expressions in the coefficients.

The problem is: This program goes on and eats up all my memory until it's killed by the kernel. Every iteration consumes only like 200kB, but this memory is never freed again.

Here is the code. The details are not that important and very bulky, therefore left out:

```
R = PolynomialRing(QQ, 2, 'bc', order='lex')
expr1, expr2, expr3 = ...

for i in range (0,50):
    for j in range(i+1,50):
        for k in range(j+1,50):
            for l in range(k+1,50):
                for m in range(l+1,50):
                    for n in range(m+1,50):
                        poly = (x-i)*(x-j)*(x-k)*(x-l)*(x-m)*(x-n)
                        r = poly.coeffs()

                        p1 = expr1.substitute(r...)
                        p2 = expr2.substitute(r...)
                        p3 = expr3.substitute(r...)

                        I = (p1, p2, p3)*R
                        B = I.groebner_basis()
```

As far as I understood python's memory management, the variables in the loop body are freed every so often. Now, it may be a programming problem, an internal python problem or some problem in the Sage routines. I don't know. Can you spot a problem with my code or is it something else?

Comment: `range` on python2 is going to BLOW YOUR MEMORY OUT OF THE WATER

Comment: Your looking at complexity of `O(n^6)`

Comment: In python 2 you could use `xrange()` over `range()` to cut down some memory usage.

Comment: Or redesign your code for less loops in loops

Comment: @JakobBowyer I know, but what does the complexity have to do with the memory? In principle the only thing that needs to be stored are 6 lists with <= 50 entries (the range ones) and then in every iteration like 6 temporary variables.

Comment: The following ask.sagemath.org question might be relevant - http://ask.sagemath.org/question/1058/memory-leak-when-doing-lots-of-ideal-tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem doesn't appear to be your loops (in python2.7, OS-X 10.5.8):

```
a = 0
for i in range (0,50):
    for j in range(i+1,50):
        for k in range(j+1,50):
            for l in range(k+1,50):
                for m in range(l+1,50):
                    for n in range(m+1,50):
                        a += 1

print( a )
```

Which takes very little additional memory on both python2.x and python3.x.

And it really doesn't take all that long to run either:

```
time python test.py
15890700

real   0m6.015s
user   0m5.940s
sys    0m0.032s
```

Perhaps something is funky when running with `sage`?  Or maybe it's something else in your loops that is causing the problem...

Comment: Thank you. It was a good idea to try the empty loops. I have now narrowed it down to the groebner_basis() routine, there seems to be a memory leak somewhere in there. Maybe I will file a bug report if that problem persists after a software update.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the bug might be the call method on multivariate polynomials. Something as innocent as:

```
` for i in xrange(really_big_number):
    polynomial(1,0,0,0)==0 `
```

will explode.

This might either happen in  `p1 = expr1.substitute(r...)` or well inside the algorithm for the Groebner Basis.